# Name for a special kind of neighborhood assignment or for the existence thereof

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology

Lets say temporarily that a topological space $(X,\tau)$ is *weird* if there is a function $\varphi:X \to \tau$ such that for all $x \in X$:

1. $x\in\varphi(x)$,
2. $\{y\in X: x \in \varphi(y)\}$ is finite.

A function satisfying the first condition is sometimes called a neighborhood assignment. Note that discrete spaces are weird and indiscrete spaces are not. Any countable Hausdorff space is weird but $\omega_1$ with the order topology is not.

**Have weird spaces been studied before? how are they called? Is there a standard name for a function satisfying both conditions?**

Comment: Very nice property! It's a bit like star-finite covering, no? (Possibly I mix up something...)

Comment: Yes @DominicvanderZypen , this has the same flavor as a star-finite covering but quite stronger. Note that if $\varphi$ takes the constant value $X$ then it produces the star-finite covering $\{X\}$ but $\varphi$ does not have property 2 (unless $X$ is finite!).